# How do I implement a plug-in architecture using RMI?

Tags: java, tomcat, plugins, classloader, rmi

I am trying to implement an RMI workflow between a Java Swing client and a Tomcat server. The difficulty that I'm having is with creating a plug-in architecture, so that users who buy our product can drop new jar files into a plug-in folder on the server, and then have those classes be available to both the client and the server.

Right now, I have the client part working: It asks the server for a list of plugin URLs, the server scans the plug-in folder and returns URLs corresponding to the jar files it finds there, and then the client uses a network class loader with those supplied URLs to dynamically load the plugin classes.

The problem occurs when the client sends objects to the server over RMI that are using the plugin classes. The server does not have these classes in its classpath (because they are just placed into a folder on the hard drive, not inside the webapp or the Tomcat folder), and so it throws an error. I need to find a solution for this.

There are a few constraints to be aware of:

- We don't want users to have to restart Tomcat when they drop new plugins into the plugin folder on the server.
- We don't want to change anything about the Tomcat installation itself, such as launch params or additional jar files, because our solution needs to be installable by customers who already have their own Tomcat running. They just want to drop our product into their webapp directory and go.

Here are some potential solutions that I've tried which did not work:

- I can't use the 'java.rmi.server.codebase' system property on the server to solve the problem, because the list of plugin jars changes at runtime, and this property is cached at startup. I would also prefer to not have to install a SecurityManager, which is required for this approach.
- Defining our own classloader and setting the 'java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoaderSpi' system property looks like exactly what we need, but when using that approach, the classloader needs to be loaded by the system classloader. Since we're running in Tomcat, which uses WebAppClassLoaders, that won't work.
- I thought about using reflection and brute-force setting our custom classloader into the 'defaultProvider' private static variable in the RMIClassLoader class, but it's final, and so I assume I can't set a new value on that (haven't actually tested).

[UPDATE - show stack trace from server]
Here is the stack trace produced by the server when the client tries to use one of the plugin classes in an RMI call to the server:

```
Jun 19, 2013 7:20:58 AM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCallException
FINE: RMI TCP Connection(4)-192.168.1.107: [192.168.1.107] exception: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prosc.cps.CPSProperties
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:294)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prosc.cps.CPSProperties
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:432)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:163)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:201)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1589)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1494)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1748)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(UnicastRef.java:306)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:288)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Although I don't understand this problem fully but for jar/plugin management at runtime, have you given OSGi a thought ?

Comment: No, I am totally ignorant of OSGi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! My system property 'java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly' on the server was set to true (which is weird, because it's documented as being false in Java 6, which is what I'm using). When this is true, the server ignores the classpath URL embedded in the class annotation from the client. I set it to false, and now the server is reading the annotations from the client and resolving the classes!

Answer (score 1):

Use the RMIClassLoaderSPI approach *at the client.* That's equivalent to dynamically setting the codebase property at the client: the classes get annotated when sent to the server via RMI so the server can load them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently, I have a URLClassLoader on the client which loads the plugin classes from an HTTP URL (that part doesn't use RMI). However, I don't understand what a client-side RMIClassLoaderSpi subclass would need to do in this scenario. Isn't that used for unmarshalling, rather than marshalling, the RMI parameters? Shouldn't whatever class does the marshalling annotate the class based on the URLClassLoader that I'm already using?

Comment: After some debugging, it looks like the classes are being correctly annotated from the client - calling 'LoaderHandler.getClassAnnotation( theObject.getClass() )' is returning a valid HTTP URL which should resolve correctly on the server: 'http://apollo.local:8080/MS/downloadExtension/CPSClient.jar' (everything is happening on a single computer, so the .local is normal). It sounds like the server is ignoring the annotation? I do have a SecurityManager installed on the server (subclassed to allow everything). Anything else I might need to do to get the server to use the annotation?

Comment: Found the answer! My system property 'java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly' was true (which is weird, because it's documented as being false in Java 6, which is what I'm using). I set it to false, and now the server is reading the annotations from the client and resolving the classes! Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction with the annotations.